# How to detect where the widget on watchOS is being displayed?

Tags: swiftui, watchos, widgetkit

I have created widget for `.accessoryRectangular` family and I use it in two places: on watch face, and from the bottom panel in watchOS 10. How do I know where it is actually displayed? I need to place different content there base on it. If it is from the bottom panel, I would rather display an image instead of a text.

[image]
[image]

In code I have it as simple as possible:

```
if family.isRectangular {
    ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .top)) {
        Image.network
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 15, height: 18)
        Text(verbatim: "      \(entry.title ?? "")")
            .font(Font.openSansRegular(withSize: 14))
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    }
}
```

How do I detect that it is displayed either in watch face (first image) or on the bottom menu (second image)?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet in watchOS 10 is the [`widgetRenderingMode` environment property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/EnvironmentValues/widgetRenderingMode), which is broadly analogous to what you want. Formally, it's giving you the rendering environment for the widget – in a complication it's likely to be `.accented`, while in the smart stack `fullColor`.

Apple gives this example code:

```swift
@Environment(\.widgetRenderingMode) var widgetRenderingMode

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
       switch renderingMode {
        case .fullColor:
           Text("Full color")
        case .accented:
           ZStack {
               Circle(...)
               VStack {
                   Text("Accented")
                       .widgetAccentable()
                   Text("Normal")
               }
           }
        case .vibrant:
           Text("Full color")
        default:
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Note that some future watch faces may try and use full color widgets. One already does – note that the [documentation for `.fullColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetrenderingmode/fullcolor) states:

> The Infograph face only uses full-color rendering when the user sets the face to multicolor. If the user selects an accent color, the system uses `accented` instead.

So it's probably worth experimenting and seeing what works best for your app's widgets.

Comment: Exactly, this is real solution;) Thank you...